# Cloud properties not read by Spring application in Cloudfoundry

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I am deploying a Spring application in Cloudfoundry which needs to access mysql database. Now as per the [tutorial](http://cloudfoundryjp.github.io/docs/using/deploying-apps/jvm/spring-service-bindings.html) , if the spring version is higher than 3.1, i can use profiles for the cloud and the cloud properties will be available for the application. The mysql service is registered as p-mysql in my case so my spring config looks like this

```
 <beans profile="cloud">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/app.conf" />
     <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" 
          p:location="file:#{systemProperties['app.conf']}" />
     <bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- DB connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db_driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${cloud.services.p-mysql.connection.jdbcUrl}" />
    <property name="user" value="${cloud.services.p-mysql.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${cloud.services.p-mysql.connection.password}" />

</bean>

</beans>
```

I need the app.conf for other keys not related to db services. When i deploy this i get the error

```
OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'datasource' defined in URL  [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/test-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-bootstrap.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'cloud.services.p-mysql.connection.jdbcUrl'
```

Is there something i missed , when i look for the env for app, i do see the properties are available for the app (cf env app_name)

What i could have missed? do i have to include

1. cloudfoundry-runtime in the pom which i dont have now?
2. or include the cloud namespace in the spring app

Comment: It may be the way the environment properties are named, the `-` and `.` may  not be getting cleanly passed in. If it is feasible try avoiding `-` and `.` and see if that works out.

Comment: Thanks @BijuKunjummen will try that out

Comment: No it didnt work out. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Any documentation that mentions `cloudfoundry-runtime` is obsolete. The [current documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html) recommends the use of Spring Cloud Connectors for Spring applications on Cloud Foundry.

You should [include Spring Cloud Connectors in your project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors#including-cloud-connectors), then you could do something as simple as this:

```
<cloud:data-source id="datasource" service-name="mysql-service"/>
```

You could also create the `datasource` bean yourself using property placeholders if you really need more control. Additional documentation on configuring Spring Cloud Connectors via XML is here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector#the-cloud-namespace

Comment: Thanks @Scott . We are using c3p0 connection pool and i am using service properties like cloud.services.solution-db.connection.jdbcurl and cloud.services.solution-db.connection.username which are working now. but for some reason its not able to find a suitable driver. If this doesnot work i can try with cloud:data-source with pool . Thanks for your help